# monitor pgadmin cpu/memory consumption for a database in realtime

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

The default dashboard for pgadmin is exactly what I want , except it doesn't have the CPU and memory consumption graph. It seems to use the admin pack extension, and the preferences section doesn't provide an option to configure it. Is there another extension or way to have the graph for CPU and memory consumption in pgadmin? (including another db client alternative to pgadmin): [image]